# BumpTop not Working

Tags: windows-7

Recently a friend of mine gave me a copy of BumpTop 2.10 (Build 6225). I had not heard of it before so I was intrigued and installed it. My friend had shown screen-shots of it and I was quite excited to try. I installed it, let it download DirectX and tried to run it. It shows the Splash Screen and then I get the BumpTop "desktop", except that it's black and then BumpTop stops responding and crashes. I've tried running it under Compatibility & with Aero disabled, but it still doesn't start. I've re-installed it 3 times, still doesn't work.
I also checked [www.bumptop.com](http://www.bumptop.com), but it says that Google's taken it over and doesn't offer any help.

Anyone have any idea why this could be happening and how I can get BumpTop to work? I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate.

One thing I did notice: I see BumpTop uses Qt 4. I already have Qt4 installed on my machine. Could this be affecting it?

**EDIT: Here's a screen-shot:**

[image: BumpTop Screen Shot]

Comment: What graphical card do you have?

Comment: It's a HP Pavilion dv5224ea Laptop (http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00725921&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=za&lang=en&product=3223530)): Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 950, Memory 128 MB (shared) (taken from site)

Comment: Try running it from command console. It might show some information there that gets lost when running a program from desktop. Also check for log files in BumpTop folder.

Comment: I'll take it you've restarted after every install...

Comment: Just ran "BumpTop.exe" from Command Line, still didn't work and nothing printed...

Comment: ...and yes I've restarted

Comment: Have you disabled Aero?

Comment: Yes I have, didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out why it kept crashing!
When I monitored BumpTop.exe with Process Monitor, I noticed that it was reading all the file in the Pictures Folder and getting stuck in a loop at one particular folder (which contained a link to itself). My thinking is that it follows links when reading the Pictures folder and then got stuck in a loop because of the link pointing to the same folder.

Anyway, deleting the link solved the problem and after an initial **very** long start-up (I have 7.2 GB of Pictures) it's now working.

Thanks to everyone who commented!